# Regular expression for one character only

Tags: regex

I need a regular expression for a string with exactly one alphabetic character in it.

For example, it should match:

- `8*x=16`
- `x+2=2`
- `u329398239823`
- `43044343k43304403`

...but not:

- `xsfdjfefljefe`
- `44434f9434343 f`
- `98(***(*)))(*)(0((-900-87`
- `32233232`

Comment: The question is not clear, what kind of expression do you want?? [a-zA-Z] does not match "8*x=16"

Comment: @simpleBob he wants expressions with only one letter it seems.

Comment: now I get it, there should be exactly one letter in the whole string

Comment: @simpleBob Are you sure that [a-zA-Z] doesn't match "8*x=16" (on the x)?

Comment: @Ryan it would not match the `=` and the `*`, or the digits. It would match the x...

Comment: @simpleBob The pattern is a single alphabetic character, which the target string does contain. Seems like a match to me. It doesn't need to match the whole string because there are no start & end anchors (e.g. ^[a-zA-Z]+$ would not be a match).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
/^[^a-z]*([a-z])[^a-z]*$/i
```

`i` for case-insensitive matching.

`^` and `$` anchors to force the regex to match the entire string.

`( )` to capture the letter.

Comment: well, what string are you testing it against?

Comment: that would match at "44434f9434343 f"

Comment: If you want it, just use a capturing group. Edited.

Comment: You can't get the letter only plus check for the whole string if there is only one letter with only one regex. If you only want the letter, you get it thanks to the capturing group. I can't get what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 3):

Try with:

```
/^[^a-z]*([a-z]{1})[^a-z]*$/gim
```

Means start of string (`^`), then any nonalpha character 0 or more times (`[^a-z]*`), then exactly one alpha char captured as first match (`([a-z]{1})`, it will be available for replacement as `$1`), and then zero or more nonalpha chars again, then the end of string (`$`).

See it in action [here](http://regexr.com?34fku).