# Regex match any single character (one character only)

Tags: regex

How do you match any one character with a regular expression?

A number of other questions on Stack Overflow sound like they promise a quick answer, but they are actually asking something more specific:

- [Regex for a string of repeating characters and another optional one at the end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19393749/regex-match-only-one-occurrence-of-character)
- [regex to match a single character that is anything but a space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181271/regex-to-match-a-single-character-that-is-anything-but-a-space)
- [Replace character in regex match only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21051031/replace-character-in-regex-match-only)

Comment: Yes, the search engines are not good at this (e.g., due to titles that are too general (unspecific)). Here is another one (it is really exactly one ***alphabetic*** character): *[Regular expression for one character only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15928216/regular-expression-for-one-character-only)*

Comment: Here is a similar basic canonical question, for which the answer is `.*`: *[Symbol for any number of any characters in regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441015/)*

Answer (score 105, accepted):

#### Match any single character

- Use the **dot** `.` character as a wildcard to match any single character.

Example regex: `a.c`

```
abc   // match
a c   // match
azc   // match
ac    // no match
abbc  // no match
```

#### Match any specific character in a set

- Use **square brackets** `[]` to match any characters in a set.
- Use `\w` to match any single alphanumeric character: `0-9`, `a-z`, `A-Z`, and `_` (underscore).
- Use `\d` to match any single digit.
- Use `\s` to match any single whitespace character.

Example 1 regex: `a[bcd]c`

```
abc   // match
acc   // match
adc   // match
ac    // no match
abbc  // no match
```

Example 2 regex: `a[0-7]c`

```
a0c   // match
a3c   // match
a7c   // match
a8c   // no match
ac    // no match
a55c  // no match
```

#### Match any character *except* ...

Use the **hat in square brackets** `[^]` to match any single character except for any of the characters that come after the hat `^`.

Example regex: `a[^abc]c`

```
aac   // no match
abc   // no match
acc   // no match
a c   // match
azc   // match
ac    // no match
azzc  // no match
```

*(Don't confuse the `^` here in `[^]` with its other usage as the start of line character: `^` = line start, `$` = line end.)*

#### Match any character optionally

Use the **optional character** `?` after any character to specify zero or one occurrence of that character. Thus, you would use `.?` to match any single character optionally.

Example regex: `a.?c`

```
abc   // match
a c   // match
azc   // match
ac    // match
abbc  // no match
```

#### See also

- [A quick tutorial to teach you the basics of regex](https://regexone.com/lesson/introduction_abcs)
- [A practice sandbox to try things out](https://regexr.com/)

Comment: This does not work if we need to match any single leading character. For example `.bc` matches `abc` and `aabc` as well.    How can we require just one character in this case?

Comment: @DinkoIvanov `\b.{1}bc\b` will do that. `{1}` stands for no more and no less than one `\b` is for word boundry.

Comment: this should be a solution rather than n guide

Answer (score 5):

**Simple answer**

If you want to match single character, put it inside those brackets **[ ]**

**Examples**

- match + ...... [+] or +
- match a ...... a
- match & ...... &

...and so on. You can check your regular expresion online on this site: https://regex101.com/

*(updated based on comment)*

Comment: The brackets are not required. You can confirm that at the site you linked to. The `+` character, since it has a special meaning, can be searched by escaping it with a backslash: `\+`.

Answer (score 2):

If you are searching for a single isolated character or a set of isolated characters within any string you can use this

```
\b[a-zA-Z]\s
```

this will find all single english characters in the string

similarly use

```
\b[0-9]\s
```

to find single digits like it will pick 9 but not 98 and so on