# Problem using hat in square brackets [^] in TFDQuery "like" pattern

Tags: sql, delphi, ms-access-2016

I have MS Access 2016 table and running TFDQuery in Delphi 10.3.

Field1 values are: `aac`, `abc`, `acc`, `a c`, `azc`, `ac`, `azzc`

I run query:

```
Select * from Table1 WHERE Field1 like 'a[^a-c]c'
```

Referring to [regex match any single character (one character only)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47545450/regex-match-any-single-character-one-character-only?rq=1), I should get:

```
"a c, azc"
```

but I am getting

```
"aac, abc, acc"
```

Please help to correct the script.

Comment: Access SQL `LIKE` doesn't do Regex. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5539141/microsoft-office-access-like-vs-regex

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To match a negative character set using the `like` operator in MS Access, you should use the exclamation mark, per the [documentation](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/like-operator-b2f7ef03-9085-4ffb-9829-eef18358e931), e.g.:

```
select * from Table1 where Field1 like 'a[!a-c]c'
```

Your current code is matching the characters `^`,`a`,`b`,`c` surrounded by the characters `a` & `c`, hence explaining the results you are currently receiving.

Per the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60016811/problem-using-hat-in-square-brackets-in-tfdquery-like-pattern/60017060#comment106143922_60017060) below by @TLama, you'll also need to [escape the exclamation mark](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Preprocessing_Command_Text_(FireDAC)#Special_Character_Processing), e.g.:

```
select * from Table1 where Field1 like 'a[!!a-c]c'
```

Comment: Don't forget to escape the `!` char when FireDAC macros are enabled.

Comment: Unfortunately the proposed script returns only `acc` when used in TFDQuery

Comment: Could you please prompt me how can I escape it?

Comment: @Rati, see [Special Character Processing](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Preprocessing_Command_Text_(FireDAC)#Special_Character_Processing) topic.

Answer (score 1):

The correct code is:

Select * from Table1 where Field1 like 'a[!!a-c]c'